# How to create a function that returns the raster value at a given latitude and longitude?

Tags: python-3.x, gdal, osgeo

Currently, I am working with some tiff files that contain information about precipitation, and I want to combine them with a pre-existing dataframe.
This dataframe has columns that give the latitude and longitude, and ultimately I want to be able to merge the precipitation values of the tiff files with dataframe for the correct latitude and longitude.
How would I find the precipitation value that corresponds to the correct latitude and longitude?

Answer (score 2):

There's a sample from GDAL Python bindings repository, `val_at_coord.py` that returns the raster value(s) for a given geographic location:

https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/gdal/swig/python/samples/val_at_coord.py

Usage:

```
val_at_coord.py [-display_xy] [longitude latitude | -coordtype=georef X Y] filename
```

> By default, the 2 first arguments are supposed to be the location in
> longitude, latitude order. If coordtype=georef is specified before the
> next 2 values will be interpreted as the X and Y coordinates  in the
> dataset spatial reference system.